# Prove the directional derivative is a linear map

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

> $\textbf{Directional Derivative:}$
>   Suppose that f is a smooth map of an open set in $\textbf{R}^n$ into $\textbf{R}^m$ and x is any point in its domain. Then for any vector $h$$\in$$\textbf{R}^n$, the derivative of $f$ in the direction $h$, taken at the point $x$ is defined by 
>   \begin{align}
> df_x(h)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}
> \end{align}
>
> $\textbf{Derivative Mapping:}$
>   With $x$ fixed, we define a mapping $df_x\colon \textbf{R}^n\to \textbf{R}^m$ by assigning to each vector h$\in\textbf{R}^n$ the directional derivative $df_x(h)\in\textbf{R}^m$.

I'm trying to prove the directional derivative mapping is linear, I know it is and that can then be used to derive the Jacobian matrix but I'm having trouble proving it, any help?

Comment: By Taylor (in a single variable and a scalar function), $f(x+th)\approx f(x)+t\dfrac{df(x+th)}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}=f(x)+th\cdot\nabla f(x)$. Repeat for all components of $f$.

Comment: That works out very nicely, thanks! :)